# Maximum directed ego network

Tags: r, igraph

My graph is this:

```
set.seed(456)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.25,directed = T)
V(g)$name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
```

I am using this function to extract my directed ego network which is incident to node a:

```
make_ego_graph(g,nodes = "a",order = 2,mode=c("in"))[[1]]
```

As using this function I can extract the directed ego network up to 2 hops. Is there any way to extract directed ego network of maximum hops from focused node "a"?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Could you use `order=length(V(g))` as that would be the max?

Comment: I have edited the question by providing reproducible graph.

Comment: What graph would the desired subset from your example graph?